# Dynamically create button using data in array and setOnClicklistener

Tags: android, loops, button, onclicklistener

im trying to add the OnClickListener to the button that it generated by the value in array, but m fail to do so, any suggestion here?

```
long lprice = Long.parseLong(searchId.getText().toString());
List<String> buttonNameOne = dbc.getItemNameRbPrice(lprice);
List<String> buttonPriceOne = dbc.getPriceRbPrice(lprice);
List<String> buttonDateOne = dbc.getCurrentDateRbPrice(lprice);

for(int i = 0 ; i < buttonNameOne.size() ;  i ++)
{
  Button btn = new Button(this);
  btn.setId(2000+i);
  btn.setText(buttonNameOne.get(i) + i);
  linearButton.addView(btn, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  Log.v("Value of element "+i, buttonNameOne.get(i));
  Log.v("Value of element "+i, buttonPriceOne.get(i));
  Log.v("Value of element "+i, buttonDateOne.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Are you adding a button to a button? `linearButton.addView(btn...)`

Comment: i divide my layout into 2 LinearLayout... and loop and create the button in the Linearlayout name "linearButton"

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049843/programmatically-dynamically-add-button-controls-to-view-using-mono-for-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is add the btn.setOnClickListener

```
for(int i = 0; i < buttonnameOne.size(); i++)
{
    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setId(2000+i);
    btn.setText(buttonNameOne.get(i) + i));
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(view v) {
            // TODO Whatever you want onclick to do
        }
    });
    //Log stuff
    linearButton.addView(btn, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```