# Monodroid add editText programmatically to layout view

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm trying to add an EditText element to my layout in Xamarin Studio using Monodroid but I can't get it working. I know how to add one in the layout and use 'FindViewById' but I'm getting the elements from a Json file so I can't access the layout.

How do I set an element to my layout programmatically with C# in Xamarin Studio?

The next examply I tried to add a TextView but that didn't work either:

```
TextView textView = new TextView (this);
textView.Text = "HALLO TEST"; 
layout.AddView (textView);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049843/programmatically-dynamically-add-button-controls-to-view-using-mono-for-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add layout parameters for the text view before you add it.

```
textView.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
```